# How to align vertex selection to an edge/vert?

Tags: vertices, snapping

TL;DR: how do I get my vert selection to align so that the two circled verts align in the Z axis?

edit: to make my question clearer, I'm looking to move *all* of the selected verts such that the two circled verts are aligned in the z-axis. I know several ways to get just the circled verts to line up.  What I need is to get the entire selection to align with the bottom of the object so that it's suitable for 3D printing.

[image]

Here's a super quick and dirty version of what I'm looking to do:
[image]

I've been searching through various snap modes and nothing really seems to work.  All of the tutorials that I've found assume you are aligning separate objects, not a selection of verts to other edges/verts in the same object in edit mode.

I've tried messing around with moving the cursor around since I assume that you have to inform Blender which of the selected verts should be treated as the origin of the selection but that has also failed to work. I'm not very familiar with manipulating the cursor though and it's likely I'm doing it wrong.  I have a hard time believing Blender doesn't have a way of doing this since this is a pretty obvious operation with mesh manipulation

Comment: Hello :). You set vertex snapping to *active* and make that vertex your active vertex :).

Comment: batFinger - none of those answers are relevant.  They are all scaling solutions, which do not answer my question.  I'm looking to move a set of verts so one specific one aligns with another vert/edge, not collapse them along an axis.

Comment: Jachym - I'm not sure what you mean by the active vertex.  I just googled that and all I get are some very confusing references to vertex groups.

Comment: Sorry misread _" I'm looking to move all of the selected verts such that the two circled verts are aligned in the z-axis"_  perhaps some idea of what "after" would look like. eg is it akin rotate around left dot till right dot at same Z?  The last selected vert is active (has a different color)

Comment: batFinfer - NP, I appreciate you trying to help.  I've added a crude edit that shows what I'm trying to do.  It's a mesh for 3D printing.  The circle is a set of verts that make up an axle.  I increased the diameter of the axle to make it stronger but need to realign it to the bottom of the object so it can lay flat on a surface for printing without needing support material.

Comment: Snapping UI not my strongpoint. So it's pretty much GZn where n is the difference of guide verts' z coordinate.

Comment: Essentially, yes.  I need to figure out how to tell Blender that of a group of selected verts, that one particular vert is the one that should be used for snapping.  I really can't imagine there isn't a way to do that but all the tutorials essentially require that I separate the selection into a new object.  I suppose I can do that but was really hoping to keep everything part of the same mesh.

Comment: @DanHeidel That's called snapping to active vertex :). See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Vertex snapping set to Active.

1. Select all the vertices you want to move
2. Make the aligning vertex active (white), by clicking it on/off while holding shift
3. Set snapping to *Vertex > Active*
4. Move cursor over the target vertex

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  That solved it.  I was a bit confused at first when I tried it, since there's multiple verts stacked on top of each other in the selection and when I de/selected one, it highlighted one somewhere further down in the stack and so the white vert wasn't visible.    Rotating the view to separate the stacked verts did show that one was marked as active and it was able to snap properly.

Comment: Glad you made it work :). Good luck with your project.